# Solve system of non-linear equations in python

Tags: python, equation, nonlinear-functions

Trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations and don't know which python solver to use.

```
a=Q1**2+Q4**2
b=2*Q1*Q2-2*Q3*Q4
c=2*Q1*Q3+2*Q2*Q4
d=Q2**2+Q3**2
```

`a,b,c,d` are just real numbers and `Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4` are the variables I want.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that's what you need:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def equations(p):
    q1, q2, q3, q4 = p
    return q1**2+q4**2, 2*q1*q2-2*q3*q4, 2*q1*q3+2*q2*q4, q2**2+q3**2


q1, q2, q3, q4 = fsolve(equations, (1, 1, 1, 1))

print(equations((q1, q2, q3, q4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's sympy library, [sympy nonlinear solve](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve)

Comment: That's for linear, OP got non-linear, they have to simplify it first

Comment: Thanks, @h4z3 I've made the edit's, overlooked it.